# Send body with get method in angular HttpClient. PostMan send body method get

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, httpclient, angular9

At the time of sending an endpoint with get and I add the body it returns value, but if I do it with angular with httpcliente, this does not show me the body to consume the backend with spring boot

[consuming with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlSBg.png)

[Cosuming with postman and httpCliente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpdBm.png)

[Backend - springboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONMew.png)

```js
header = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.auth.isToken())
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('Accept-Language', 'UTF-8')
    .set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');

const url = 'api/servicios/servicios-impuestos-clientes';

const object = JSON.stringify(body);

const options = {
    headers: this.header,
    body: JSON.stringify({ 'impuestos' [1, 2] }),
    // tslint:disable-next-line: quotemark
    // tslint:disable-next-line: object-literal-shorthand
    params: new HttpParams().append('cliente', 1 + '')
};

console.log(options);
return this.http.get<Servicios>(url, options).pipe(map(result => {
    return result;
}));
```

Comment: You can pass params in `HTTPGET` request, For sending body you need to use `POST` request.

Comment: So, the postman allows to send the body by get method, but httpClient doesn't allow it, right?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9927#issuecomment-437651355

Answer (score 0):

Usually a GET does not have a body. That's why most HTTP clients do not allow it.

But it's possible.

Checkout this question: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)